# WakeLock under-locked exception using cwac-locpoll

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm using cwac-locpoll and it's been doing a great job. However, some of my users are getting the following problem

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: WakeLock under-locked com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPoller
at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.release(PowerManager.java:339)
at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.release(PowerManager.java:299)
at com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.WakefulThread.onPostExecute(WakefulThread.java:59)
at com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPollerService$PollerThread.onPostExecute(LocationPollerService.java:231)
at com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.WakefulThread.run(WakefulThread.java:93)
```

Here is my `LocationReceiver` class which, as you can see, just stores the obtained location in my app `SharedPreferences` via a helper class.

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "LocationReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        Location loc = (Location) b.get(LocationPoller.EXTRA_LOCATION);

        if (loc == null) {
            loc = (Location) b.get(LocationPoller.EXTRA_LASTKNOWN);

            if (loc == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unable to get location. " + intent.getStringExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_ERROR));
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Timeout getting location, using previous one " + loc);
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Got location " + loc);
        }

        // save location in preferences
        if (loc != null) {
            PrefsHelper.setLastLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also using a separate cwac-wakeful `WakefulIntentService` that fetches this last location and does something, but they are designed to run indepentendly. In other words:

1. `LocationReceiver` is called by cwac-locpoll to store the last known location in the `SharedPreferences` every now and then.
2. A `WakefulIntentService` is (independently) scheduled to fetch this location and do something with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to your `BroadcastReceiver`, in all likelihood. I need to ripple some recent changes to `WakefulIntentService` over to `LocationPoller` to better handle edge cases, like where Android gets rid of the service and brings it back later on, which may help here.

I have [filed an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll/issues/5) on this -- please track that issue for notes about when a fix is released. Given the nature of this component, I need to have a long-running test, so it will probably be at least 24 hours before I can release a patch.

Comment: Thanks @CommowsWare for the quick response. I'll definitely keep an eye open for the patch.

Comment: As per CommonsWare's answer, the issue seems to have been addressed and fixed in [v0.2.1](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll/issues/5). We have not experienced the issue since switching to that version.